# sed or awk regex, stop matching after semi-colon

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I have a multiple strings in a file that looks like this

```
TXT 20131101 094502,20131101 094502,Fri Nov  1 09:45:02 UTC 2013;
```

I want a regex that will get everything after TXT and only display that up until the ; using sed or awk

I have tried many ways but I cant seem to get it to stop at the ;

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want a regex that will get everything after TXT and only display
>   that up until the ;

```
grep -oP 'TXT[^;]*' filename
```

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{print $1}' filename
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\([^;]*\).*/\1/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed "s/TXT\([^;]*\);.*/\1/"
```

between TXT (so also first space if any) and first ; (not included)

reply from devnull include the "TXT" in the output